# How to return partial view without site redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to return the result of some action in a partial view.
So if for example creating a user fails the partialview should return an error message.
But instead of return the partial view a redirection to controller/action happens

The site:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rollen und Rechte";
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Role", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, //target element(#mydiv) will be replaced
    UpdateTargetId = "mydiv"
}))
{
    <table cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Rollenname:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Name" id="roleNameVal" placeholder="Neue Rolle" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <label id="resultLabel"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn_click" />

    <div id="mydiv">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("_CreateResult");
        }
    </div>
}
```

The Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult Create(FormCollection val1)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                var value = val1.GetValue("name").AttemptedValue + "CREATED";

                var res = new Result()
                {
                    Success = true,
                    ResultValue = value
                };
                return PartialView("_CreateResult", res);
            }
            catch
            {
                return PartialView("bla");
            }
        }
```

The Partial View

```
@model planemosIdUi.Dto.Result

@{
      ViewBag.Title = "_CreateResult";
}
@{
    if (Model?.Success == true)
    {
        <label>Erstellt</label>
    }
    else if(Model?.Success == false)
    {
        <label>Fehler</label>
    }
    else
    { 
        <label>Do something</label>
    }
}
```

So what happens is that the partial view is returned but not on the index site as i would expect it where the div should be changed.
The partial view is returned on a redirect site

it redirects from

Roles/Index to Roles/Create

But i want just the div to be updated

Answer (score 0):

Use this type of ajax call:

```
function loadComapnyUser() {       
    $.ajax({           
        type: "POST",           
        url: "/YourControllerName/GetCompanyAllUsers",
        contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#YourDivId").append(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // alert("failed");
        }
    });
}
```